# Uninstall and re-install of Anaconda 2.7 won't fix kernel problem in Jupyter

Tags: python-2.7

I am in a VM environment (Win 7 VirtualBox) and had gotten the Anaconda 2.7 suite to work.

Being new to Python, I was working on some code that instructed me to install PythonWin to do some connection with Crystal Reports. Seemed to install OK but then started getting some errors about the kernel in Jupyter not starting.

Uninstalled everything and I think got rid of any bad links and such from the previous installs.

Did the fresh install of Anaconda 2.7 and did NOT install PythonWin. Now stuck with a broken/unable to load kernel in Jupyter. Here's the error below. All help much appreciated from this newbie. Thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1592, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 261, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 73, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 261, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 261, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 261, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 160, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 259, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 204, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 138, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 644, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0):

Figure I'll close the loop since I've found a solution - after uninstalling everything related to Anaconda and going through the file system and deleting all Anaconda related folders I re-installed Anaconda 2.7 as admin. Also during the setup I selected the choice to make the program available to all users.

Install finished and Anaconda 2.7 and all the modules worked as expected.